# My class is mostly a front for a container, should I expose this fact?

Tags: c++, abstraction, standard-library

In my design I have a class that is mostly a front for a `std::vector<OtherClass>`.  Should I, in my class interface, hand over to any caller an `std::iterator`, hand over a reference to the whole `vector` or provide a set of functions to access the contents of my `vector`?  Or approach it differently altogether?

More information: The elements in the container will be set up during initialization, and will not be added to when the program is running normally.  The clients of my class will often do queries and modify the state of the `OtherClass` elements, though not in a time-critical fashion.

Comment: Consider using free functions accepting `std::vector` instead of members of a wrapper class.

Comment: This is very application specific. Iterators might work, but what if you are constantly adding to the vector? Iterators would be invalidated when the vector reallocates. Give us more information, please!

Comment: If `OtherClass` is constant, why not specialize ?

Comment: Will your class *always* front `vector` or could it change to `list` or `deque` behind the scenes? If it changes, do you mind breaking all your users' code?

Comment: Looks like design question and who could answer that better than yourself? Object hides implementation details. If you do not want to expose implementation details - write your own iterator wrappers and std::vector API wrappers. Perhaps you really need to control input values or perform data modifications. Too few information in fact to give you any advice.

Answer (score 1):

You should create the functions to modify the vector internally. Here's why:

Depending on the Compiler, you might be running different versions of STL (Standard Template Library), which can cause unexpected issues, hypothetically they could change the way std::vector operates from when you build it in an older (or newer) version of the library and send it off.

However, I am guessing this is not a library, or a project to be potentially used with another compiler. You are safe to send a reference or pointer to the vector **as long as you** run and compile with the same version of STL.